# Prepared Statements Php Mysql "WHERE INSTR..."

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Welcome,
I have 500 error using it...

my code:

```
$cont_search = "some";
    $sql_take_results = "SELECT id,typeset,name,description,first_col,second_col,author,cop_times,add_time FROM sets WHERE typeset='public' AND (INSTR(name,'?')>0 OR INSTR(description,'?')>0 OR INSTR(first_col,'?')>0 OR INSTR(second_col,'?')>0 OR INSTR(author,'?')>0) ORDER BY cop_times DESC";
$stmt_take_results = $conn->prepare($sql_take_results);
$stmt_take_results->bind_param("sssss",$cont_search,$cont_search,$cont_search,$cont_search,$cont_search);
$stmt_take_results->execute();
$stmt_take_results->bind_result($s_id,$s_typeset,$s_name,$s_desc,$s_fcol,$s_scol,$s_author,$s_cop_times,$s_add_time);
$stmt_take_results->fetch();
$stmt_take_results->close();
```

what's wrong? :/

Comment: please add more details

Comment: i want to take from datebase rows where are records which contain my sub string($cont_search) using prepared statements

Comment: Error 500 : what says the log?

Comment: "HTTP ERROR 500" and nothing more

Comment: Remove the quotes around the question marks.

Comment: i did it, still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the single quotes aren't necessary with the bind parameter, even for strings:

```
$sql_take_results = "SELECT id,typeset,name,description,first_col,second_col,author,cop_times,add_time FROM sets WHERE typeset='public' AND (INSTR(name,?)>0 OR INSTR(description,?)>0 OR INSTR(first_col,?)>0 OR INSTR(second_col,?)>0 OR INSTR(author,?)>0) ORDER BY cop_times DESC";
```

Comment: i did it, still the same

Comment: Well you probably have something else too...put the code in a try/catch and echo the message as a starting point...good exception handling is fundamental to figuring out problems

Comment: omg, i had on top of script "session_start():" instead "session_start();"